# how to delete cache on my VPS Ubuntu Server. Whatever I write on any page is never shown

Tags: django, ubuntu, vps

No matter what I do on the pages nothing is shown. Even if I write "hello" on my index.html page it will not show it. The server only shows what I pulled from github a week ago. Nothing, no change. I added the sentry logging tool, it takes zero notice, I copied pasted the logging snippet used and it completely ignores it. I write an extra word on the menu bar at the top, nothing is shown.

I tried this to remove the cache, no effect

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

on the menu bar, I added an "x"  here and it is not shown! This is insane! About usx

```
<a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">{% blocktrans %}About usxc {% endblocktrans %}</a>
```

I am using gunicorn, nginx and supervisor for django. I have reloaded gninx but it makes no difference. I just can't believe that a simple "hello" hard written on my index.html page  won't show.

Comment: You've added Django as a tag, are you using caching in there, or how are you implementing it? What web-server are you using to serve your app, does that have caching enabled?

Comment: Hello. I am using django, running gunicorn, nginx and supervisor. I have reloaded nginx but it makes no difference. Configuration of niginx is correct nginx -t perfect. I don't know the answer to your question "using caching in Django", I haven't done anything explicitly there related to cache. where can I see that of "caching enabled"? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

while indeed I was writing plain text on my html and was truly going hysteric about not seeing changes, I had also added python code to include sentry in my settings.py, however, that shouldn't have affected the html code managed by nginx, well, somehow it id. So I restarted the whole thing via supervisor like `sudo system sudo supervisorctl restart your_gunicorn_process_name`

I was about to suffer a stroke as my heart was performing incredible acrobatics when I refreshed my web url and I saw a big blank Bad gateway 502 nginx error, BUT, sentry had loaded and I could see the issues. I manually restarted my gunicorn script file and everything was up and running and the changes were showing.
So, long story short: I restarted every freeking thing, first via supervisor and then the gunicorn manually.
Three days of frustration.